# Color of the circle in enumerate items in Beamer

Tags: beamer

I want to use the color of the circle in enumerate items. How can I do it? Here it is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}

\mode<article> % only for the article version
{
  \usepackage{fullpage}
  \usepackage{hyperref}
  \usepackage{enumerate}
}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading][bottom=red!10,top=blue!10]

  \usetheme{JuanLesPins}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  \usefonttheme{serif}
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\setbeamertemplate{items}[circle]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{enumerate}

\item My first item...

\item In my second item, I want to use the color which is in item circles on this word {\color{blue}WORD}. How can I do it?

\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{\color{item projected.bg}WORD}` to get the colour of the enumerate item, however for most themes a simple `\structure{WORD}` should give the same result.

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}

\mode<article> % only for the article version
{
  \usepackage{fullpage}
  \usepackage{hyperref}
  \usepackage{enumerate}
}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading][bottom=red!10,top=blue!10]

  \usetheme{JuanLesPins}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  \usefonttheme{serif}
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\setbeamertemplate{items}[circle]



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{enumerate}

\item My first item...

\item In my second item, I want to use the color which is in item circles on this word {\color{item projected.bg}WORD}. How can I do it?

\item In my second item, I want to use the color which is in item circles on this word \structure{WORD}. How can I do it?

\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]